# Почему неправильно работает растяжение виджетов при их анимации

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qlayout, qpropertyanimation

Пытаюсь создать анимированное расширяемое меню. 
Вроде бы создал, но работает криво: при его обратном закрытии кнопки не возвращаются в исходное положение.

Пытался растягивать `self.vbox_1`, но не получилось.

Как я могу сделать так, чтобы все виджеты растягивались и стягивались корректно?

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.clicks = 0
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,35,35)")
        self.setMinimumSize(1000,500)

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.top_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,35,35);")
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)
        self.top_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.content = QFrame()
        self.content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45,45,45);")
        self.content.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.left_bar = QStackedWidget()
        self.left_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,35,35);")
        self.left_bar.setMaximumWidth(80)
        self.left_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.menu_frame = QFrame()
        self.menu_frame.setFixedSize(80,40)
        self.menu_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(110, 192, 255);")

        self.menu_button = QPushButton(self.menu_frame)
        self.menu_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;\
                                        border: 0px solid; font: 14pt; color: rgb(35,35,35);")
        self.menu_button.setText("Menu")
        self.menu_button.setMinimumSize(80,40)

        self.page_1_button = QPushButton(self.left_bar)
        self.page_1_button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover { background-color: rgb(85,170,255) }\
                                          QPushButton:!hover { background-color: transparent; border: 0px solid; font: 11pt; color: rgb(255,255,255) }")
        self.page_1_button.setText("Page 1")
        self.page_1_button.setGeometry(0,0,80,40)

        self.page_2_button = QPushButton(self.left_bar)
        self.page_2_button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover { background-color: rgb(85,170,255) }\
                                          QPushButton:!hover { background-color: transparent; border: 0px solid; font: 11pt; color: rgb(255,255,255) }")
        self.page_2_button.setText("Page 2")
        self.page_2_button.setGeometry(0, 40, 80, 40)

        self.vbox_1 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.menu_frame)
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.left_bar)

        self.vbox_2 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.content)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox_1)
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox_2)

        self.menu_button.clicked.connect(self.toggle)

    def toggle(self):
        self.clicks+=1
        array = [self.menu_frame,self.menu_button,self.left_bar,self.page_1_button,self.page_2_button]
        for i in array:
            self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(i, b"minimumWidth")
            self.animation.setDuration(50)

            if self.clicks%2 == 1:
                self.animation.setStartValue(80)
                self.animation.setEndValue(140)
            else:
                self.animation.setStartValue(140)
                self.animation.setEndValue(80)

            self.animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.OutBounce)
            self.animation.start()

            QTest.qWait(70)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: что значит "при обратном закрытии"

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы меню вернулось в исходное положение 80, я это имел ввиду под закрытием

Comment: При self.clicks%2 == 1 я хотел бы, чтобы self.animation.setStartValue(140), а self.animation.setEndValue(80), я добавил в код вопроса этот момент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте `self.left_bar = QFrame()`

Добавьте в `left_bar` кнопки.

Примените анимацию к `left_bar`:

```
self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.left_bar, b"minimumWidth")
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.clicks = 0
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,35,35)")
        self.setMinimumSize(1000, 500)

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.top_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,35,35);")
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)
        self.top_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.content = QFrame()
        self.content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(145,45,45);")
        self.content.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

# left_bar
        self.left_bar = QFrame()
        self.left_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,135,35);")        
        self.left_bar.setMaximumWidth(80)
        self.left_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

# menu_button
        self.menu_button = QPushButton()        
        self.menu_button.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #22aa55;          /* transparent */  
            border: 0px solid; 
            font: 14pt; 
            color: rgb(235,35,35);
        """)
        self.menu_button.setText("Menu")
        self.menu_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.menu_button.clicked.connect(self.toggle)

# page_1_button
        self.page_1_button = QPushButton()        
        self.page_1_button.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton:hover { 
                background-color: rgb(85,170,255) 
            }
            QPushButton:!hover { 
                background-color: transparent; 
                border: 0px solid; 
                font: 11pt; 
                color: rgb(255,255,255) 
            }
        """)
        self.page_1_button.setText("Page 1")
        self.page_1_button.setMinimumHeight(40)

# self.page_2_button
        self.page_2_button = QPushButton()        
        self.page_2_button.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton:hover { 
                background-color: rgb(85,170,255) 
            }
            QPushButton:!hover { 
                background-color: transparent; 
                border: 0px solid; 
                font: 11pt; 
                color: rgb(255,255,255) 
            }
        """)
        self.page_2_button.setText("Page 2")
        self.page_2_button.setMinimumHeight(40)

        self.vbox_1 = QVBoxLayout(self.left_bar)
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.menu_button)
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.page_1_button)
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.page_2_button)
        self.vbox_1.addStretch() 
        self.vbox_1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.right_bar = QFrame()
        self.right_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        
        self.vbox_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.right_bar)   
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.content)
        self.vbox_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.vbox_2.setSpacing(0)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
#        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox_1)
#        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox_2)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.right_bar)

    def toggle(self):
        # print(f'self.left_bar.width() -- {self.left_bar.width()}') #     
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.left_bar, b"minimumWidth")
        self.animation.setDuration(2000)

#        if self.clicks%2 == 1:
        if self.left_bar.width() == 80:
            self.animation.setStartValue(80)
            self.animation.setEndValue(140)
        else:
            self.animation.setStartValue(140)
            self.animation.setEndValue(80)

        self.animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.OutBounce)
        self.animation.start()

# ???            QTest.qWait(1170)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Частично решил твою проблему, но вторая кнопка ведет себя неадекватно. Костыль, конечно, но думаю, что это даст тебе верное направление.

```
def toggle(self):
    self.clicks+=1
    array = [self.menu_frame,self.menu_button,self.left_bar,self.page_1_button,self.page_2_button]
    for i in array:
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(i, b"minimumWidth")
        self.animation.setDuration(200)

        if self.clicks%2 == 1:
            self.animation.setStartValue(80)
            self.animation.setEndValue(140)
        else:
            ################
            self.menu_button.setGeometry(0, 0, 80, 40)
            self.page_1_button.setGeometry(0, 0, 80, 40)
            self.page_2_button.setGeometry(0, 40, 80, 40)
            ################
            self.animation.setStartValue(140)
            self.animation.setEndValue(80)

        self.animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.OutBounce)
        self.animation.start()

        QTest.qWait(70)
```